# Porting ArcGIS Engine to ArcGISRuntime SDK for .NET, dealing with interior/exterior polygon rings

Tags: arcgis-engine, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, geopackage

I've inherited some code that converts ArcGIS Engine `IPolygon4` objects to GeoPackage-compatible objects. The format is very specific in terms of what's permitted with exterior and interior rings.

I need to port this code to ArcGIS Runtime for use on Android. The API for the Runtime polygon class `Polygon` is really sparse, and contains no properties or methods related to the polygon's rings. The only property I have is an `IReadOnlyList<ReadOnlyPart>` holding the polygon's parts.

I don't know if this collection is ordered, or if I can order it in some way to determine which ring is the exterior one.

Is there any way that I can identify the interior/exterior rings of a `Polygon` in ArcGISRuntime SDK for .NET?

Here is the code I am working with. `WkbMultiPolygon` is the custom polygon object I am trying to convert to.

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using System.Linq;

public static WkbMultiPolygon CreateMultiPolygon(IPolygon4 esriPolygon) {

    var exteriorRingGeometryCollection = (IGeometryCollection)esriPolygon.ExteriorRingBag;

    var exteriorRingCount = exteriorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount;

    // create my list of custom polygons
    var wkbPolygons = new List<WkbPolygon>(exteriorRingCount);

    for(var exteriorRingIndex = 0; exteriorRingIndex < exteriorRingCount; ++exteriorRingIndex) {
        var exteriorRingGeometry = exteriorRingGeometryCollection.Geometry[exteriorRingIndex];

        var interiorRingCollection = (IGeometryCollection)esriPolygon.InteriorRingBag[exteriorRingGeometry as IRing];

        // create my custom polygon object and add to list.
        wkbPolygons.Add(new WkbPolygon(ToLinearRing(exteriorRingGeometry as IPointCollection),
                                       Enumerable.Range(0, interiorRingCollection.GeometryCount)
                                                 .Select(index => interiorRingCollection.Geometry[index] as IPointCollection)
                                                 .Select(ToLinearRing)
                                                 .ToList()));
    }

    return new WkbMultiPolygon(wkbPolygons);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet that illustrates where you are stuck, please?

Comment: Possibly the only thing I can think of is that Exterior rings are clockwise and Interior rings (holes) are counter-clockwise, if you can get to the points from the ring then you could be able to determine direction of travel to decide if a ring is exterior or interior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the approach I used here:

https://github.com/dotMorten/GeometryConversions/blob/master/src/GeometryConversions.Shared/Utilities.cs#L12